# bashrc in custom folder

Tags: bash, configuration, bashrc

I want to cleanup my home folder and have managed to move out most of the configuration files to the .config folder. But, one file I'm not able to figure out is the `.bashrc` file. How can I specify bash to load .bashrc from a custom location?

Answer (score 8):

The `bash` command [accepts a `--rcfile filename` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash-1) that will:

> Execute commands from filename (instead of ~/.bashrc) in an interactive shell.

So if you run `bash --rcfile ~/.config/bashrc` then you will load that file instead.

There *isn't* a way to configure it to load from there by default (where would you configure it?), other than recompiling it with modifications (change the definition of `bashrc_file` in `shell.c` - it's not a configuration option). You can create a wrapper that runs `bash` with the `--rcfile` option and passes all other arguments along unchanged - you'd have to add it to `/etc/shells` to be able to set that wrapper as your shell, and you'd have to be careful doing it. Either of those options is viable, but nontrivial to get right.

If you're on a single-user system, another option is to place all your configuration in the system-wide files in `/etc`, but that isn't really solving the problem. You could also have the system-wide file detect how it was run and re-execute `bash` with the `--rcfile` option automatically, but that seems even more fraught than the other approaches.

---

My recommendation would be to acclimatise yourself to having an extra dotfile in your home directory, but the above approaches are doable if you really can't.

Comment: Why isn't placing all configuration in the system-wide files in `/etc` solving the problem? Surely that solves it completely?

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by Gnouc answer, I realized that bash reads `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` in the same cases. Thus, you can put at the bottom of `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
 if [ -s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/bash/bashrc" ]; then
    . "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/bash/bashrc"
 fi
```

and then move `~/.bashrc` to `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/bash/bashrc`

Bash will still attempt to load the `~/.bashrc` which is not a problem since it no longer exists. And `/etc/bash.bashrc` will ensure that the file is loaded from your new location.

Answer (score 4):

With a login shell, typically, your `~/.bash_profile` contains the line:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

So you can set your own config folder here:

```
BASHRC_CONFIG_DIR=~/config/bash

if [ -f "$BASHRC_CONFIG_DIR/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$BASHRC_CONFIG_DIR/.bashrc"
fi
```

For non-login shell, you can set it in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: This will only work for a login shell (which doesn't otherwise load .bashrc). If you open an interactive shell inside a session (xterm, gnome-terminal… or you simply call bash again) it will only read ~/.bashrc and in your case would fail to load ~/.config/bash

Comment: @Ángel: Added it, forgot about that.